# Creating columns (like Word) and justify the text in pdf document using iTextSharp c#

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm working in a "study" project which perform the function of cash register. It have the basics, add products with name and price, can bill to customers. I created a method that takes all created products (loaded in a collection) and creates a price list in a PDF document. The final result is something like this:
[image: price_list.pdf]

A bit ugly. Now, how can I create three columns that limit the characters in each one? Like Office Word:
[image: Price list in Office Word] As you can see, in Word we can create columns (in my case three, with the lines visible). It is possible using iTextSharp? I searched but I couldn't find anything. And how to align the name on the left and the price on the right regardless of the length of the name, again as Word?

Comment: ITextSharp has plenty of great examples on their site, have you checked there first.

Comment: @MethodMan Yep. I checked all the sites possibles.

Comment: Have you looked at this example: https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/columntext-examples/objects-columns#1310-columntextparagraphs2.java ? It shows how to add text in columns.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a school project (I'm not sure what you meant when you wrote *"I'm working in a "study" project"*), you can show off to your teacher by using iText 7 instead of the outdated iTextSharp.

> By the way: we don't call it iTextSharp anymore: it's now called iText for .NET, which explains why there is no iTextSharp tag on Stack Overflow anymore.

iText 7 comes with a `ColumnDocumentRenderer` that allows you to define nice columns (see [chapter 2](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-2) of the tutorial). Most of the tutorials are in Java, because a good C# developer is supposed to know how to read Java, but there's also a .NET tutorial with a columns example. See [chapter 3](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net/chapter-3-using-renderers-and-event-handlers) of the .NET version of the iText 7 jump-start tutorial:

```
Document document = new Document(pdf, ps);
//Set column parameters
float offSet = 36;
float columnWidth = (ps.GetWidth() - offSet * 2 + 10) / 3;
float columnHeight = ps.GetHeight() - offSet * 2;
//Define column areas
Rectangle[] columns = new Rectangle[] {
    new Rectangle(offSet - 5, offSet, columnWidth, columnHeight),
    new Rectangle(offSet + columnWidth, offSet, columnWidth, columnHeight),
    new Rectangle(offSet + columnWidth * 2 + 5, offSet, columnWidth, columnHeight)
};
document.SetRenderer(new ColumnDocumentRenderer(document, columns));
```

If you want the nice tabbing, you can use the `TabStop` class as explained in [chapter 3](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-3) of the building blocks tutorial.

However, the iText 5 code is much less intuitive than the iText 7 code. I can expand my answer if you *need* an iText 5 solution, but be aware that if I were your teacher, I would fail you for using iText 5. So before I give you an iText 5 answer, I'd need some written proof that your teacher insists on an iText 5 solution.

Comment: Thanks for answer. My teacher didn't said what version of iText I have to use, so I think I can use 7. I saw the example in chapter 2, the ColumnDocumentRenderer, but I don't know how to use it in C#. I know Java, but I couldn't find the method for .NET

Comment: Which method is missing according to you? I see `SetRenderer(DocumentRenderer documentRenderer)` in [Document.cs](https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet/blob/develop/itext/itext.layout/itext/layout/Document.cs) and I see the [DocumentRenderer.cs](https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet/blob/develop/itext/itext.layout/itext/layout/ColumnDocumentRenderer.cs) class, You have to be more clear about what exactly it is you can't find. Are you sure you're looking at iText 7?